# Funcion Case When varias columnas

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

no se si es posible realizar lo siguiente:

Tengo esta funcion Case en mi consulta:

```
SELECT t6x.plant_id,
 CASE 
  WHEN plant_id = 74
     THEN 'OESTE'
  WHEN plant_id = 82
     THEN 'OESTE'
  WHEN  plant_id = 84
     THEN 'OESTE'
  WHEN  plant_id = 100
     THEN 'OESTE'
        WHEN plant_id = 114
     THEN 'OESTE'
  WHEN plant_id = 216
     THEN 'OESTE'
  WHEN  plant_id = 1868
     THEN 'OESTE'
  WHEN  plant_id = 1886
     THEN 'ESTE'
  WHEN plant_id = 105
     THEN 'ESTE'
  WHEN plant_id = 152
     THEN 'ESTE'
 WHEN plant_id = 154
     THEN 'ESTE'
 WHEN plant_id = 1877
     THEN 'ESTE'
 WHEN plant_id = 1891
     THEN 'ESTE'
  ELSE 'OUT CLUSTER'
 END AS CLUSTER
```

FROM T6X

Necesito mostrar en otras columnas en base a ese mismo case otros valores:
Son alrededor de seis columnas mas donde tengo que mostrar otro valor en base al mismo case, la pregunta es hay alguna forma de simplificar esto concatenar los case?

```
SELECT t6x.plant_id,
 CASE 
  WHEN plant_id = 74
     THEN 'CENTRO'
  WHEN plant_id = 82
     THEN 'CENTRO'
  WHEN  plant_id = 84
     THEN 'CENTRO'
   ETC ETC......
  ELSE 'OUT REGION'
 END AS REGION
```

FROM T6X

Imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes crear una [funcion](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370)

Comment: @Bryro
Tengo nula experiencia en el uso de funciones.

Comment: ¿Por que plant_id = 74 en un caso es CENTRO y en otro OESTE?

Comment: @Bryro Fue un error de dedo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero que nada: ¿No tienes ya los textos en alguna tabla?, es decir, la entidad a la que apunta `plant_id`, no tiene un atributo que indique si se trata de `'CENTRO'`, `'OESTE'` `'ESTE'` o `'OUT CLUSTER'`?

Si la respuesta es no, es un buen momento para plantearte crear una tabla o modificar alguna existente para agregar este atributo. Si no tienes posibilidad de hacerlo, y estás obligado a definir esta relación de los textos con los `plant_id` de manera "dura" en la consulta, podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
with tipos as (
  select  74 as id, 'OESTE' as nombre from dual UNION
  select 82, 'OESTE' from dual UNION
  select 84, 'OESTE' from dual UNION
  select 100, 'OESTE' from dual UNION
  select 114, 'OESTE' from dual UNION
  select 116, 'OESTE' from dual UNION
  select 216, 'OESTE' from dual UNION
  select 1868, 'OESTE' from dual UNION
  select 1886, 'ESTE' from dual UNION
  select 105, 'ESTE' from dual UNION
  select 1877, 'ESTE' from dual UNION
  select 1891, 'ESTE' from dual UNION
  select 154, 'ESTE' from dual UNION
  select 152, 'ESTE' from dual
)

select nvl(t1.nombre, 'OUT REGION'),
       nvl(t2.nombre, 'OUT REGION'),
       nvl(t3.nombre, 'OUT REGION')
  from T6X
  left join tipos t1
    on t1.id = T6X.plant_id
  left join tipos t2
    on t2.id = T6X.plant_id_2
  left join tipos t3
    on t3.id = T6X.plant_id_3
;
```

Detalle:

- Usamos un "common table expresion" para definir dinámicamente una tabla `tipos` que hará de reemplazo del `CASE`, obviamente lo óptimo sería tener una tabla física, pero también podemos hacer esto o incluso definir una tabla temporal.
- La idea es reutilizar `tipos` las veces que haga falta mediante varios `LEFT JOIN`, por cada columna que necesites
- En caso que un `plant_id` no tenga un `nombre` definido, retornaremos `'OUT REGION'`, tal como hace el `ELSE` del `CASE`.
- Ten en cuenta cuando no usas una tabla física a la que podrías crearle índices, como es este caso, que tendrás seguramente una penalidad en la performance.

Por otro lado si tuvieras que "heredar" múltiples valores pero siempre relacionados a un único `id`, serí incluso más sencillo, tu tabla dinámica podría ser algo así:

```
with tipos as (
      select  74 as id, 
              'OESTE' as cluster,
              'NORTE' as regiones,
              'PLANTA4' as plantas,
              'MEXICO' as pais
              from dual 
      UNION
      select  100 as id, 
              'OESTE' as cluster,
              'NOROESTE' as regiones,
              'PLANTA50' as plantas,
              'MEXICO' as pais
              from dual 
      UNION
      ...
)
select nvl(t1.cluster, 'OUT REGION')  as cluster,
       nvl(t1.regiones, 'SIN REGION') as regiones,
       nvl(t1.plantas, 'SIN PLANTA')  as plantas
       nvl(t1.plantas, 'SIN pais')    as pais
      from T6X
      left join tipos t1
        on t1.id = T6X.plant_id
```

[Fiddle de ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43ade/1/0)

Comment: Respondiendo a sus preguntas, la tabla si tiene algunos textos y como id plant_id pero necesito convertirlos a los datos que necesito, el DBArealizara los cambios pero en unos meses mas y yo necesito idearme algo para trabajar con la data correcta.

Tengo un par de dudas:
El código funciona bien solo que en las columnas no requiero la misma informacion si no algo como la imagen mostrada en la edicion de la pregunta.
La otra duda es como puedo agregar nombres de columnas especificos?
Como puedo mostrar los datos creados (ficticios) con datos de la tabla (select)

Comment: @JoseDanielSolis, te refieres a que además de `cluster` tendrías que contemplar otras tablas como `regiones`, `plantas` o `paises`?

Comment: No todas las columnas Cluster, Regiones, Plantas Pais estan estan ligadas a la misma tabla y ID

Comment: Creo que te entiendo, verifica mi última edición

Comment: Gracias Patricio va de maravilla tu aportación........!